# I Want to create nested recyclerview using date filter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arraylist

I want to create a nested recycler view like this

[image]

but I can't find a way to do it, I have tried some filter method but did not get my required output.
I am fetching data from some API.
filter :

```
fun group_check(date:String,aList: ArrayList<DataItem>): List<DataItem> {
    return  aList.filter { it ->
        it.createdDate == date
    }
}
```

but I am getting this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to use two recyclerview ,one in your activity another one in adapter

code Structure
in main xml
put one recycler view

in adapterlayout.xml
Put one textview below text view put recycler view

Adapter Code
inside onBindViewHolder
holder.textDate.setText(messageData.getDate());
getAllMessageList=messageItems.get(position).getGetAllMessages();
if(getAllMessageList.size()>0)
TransctionHistory adapter;
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
adapter = new TransctionHistory adapter(getAllMessageList,context);
holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

your array should be like

```
          result:[{
date:September 20
array:[{name:addmoney,date:sep 20}]
},

{
date:September 23
tosort:[{name:Paid to Xyz,date:sep 20},{name:patmhistory,date:sep 20}]
}
]
```

if you want to sort above array tosort[]  using Collection

```
Collections.sort(tosort, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return o1.getDateTime().lt(o2.getDateTime()) ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```

if you have any doubt you can msg